# Refresh the page after user allowing location

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am using Nominatim API to get the user's address from the latitude and longitude (using the geolocation HTML5 API to get these).
This is my block of code for the geolocation API:

```
function geoFindMe() {
  function success(position) {
    localStorage.setItem('pos_lat', position.coords.latitude);
    localStorage.setItem('pos_lon', position.coords.longitude);
  }

  function error() {
    elLocation.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
  }

  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    elLocation.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
  } else {
    elLocation.textContent = 'Locating…';
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  }
}
```

I am saving the latitude and longitude of the user in the local storage because I didn't find a way to return these values. I need these because in other function I am using Nominatim API to get the address from the lat and lon.

Now, my problem is, the first time the user visits the website his localStorage is empty. And the address can not be fetched while the user does not allow me to know his location. My solution would be refreshing the page after the user allows but I do not know how to do it, can someone please help me with this or other solution?

**Edit:** I will just add the block of code where I am getting the address:

```
async function getLocationData() {
  geoFindMe();
  const latitude = localStorage.getItem('pos_lat');
  const longitude = localStorage.getItem('pos_lon');
  let url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if(!response.ok) throw response;
  const data = await response.json();

  let locationAddress = {};
  locationAddress.village = data.address.village;
  locationAddress.city = data.address.city;
  locationAddress.country = data.address.country;
  locationAddress.countryCode = data.address.country_code;

  return locationAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
  function getLocationData() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
        } else {
            return 'Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.';
        }
    }

    async function success(position) {
        let url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lon=${position.coords.longitude}`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) throw response;
        const data = await response.json();

        let locationAddress = {};
        locationAddress.village = data.address.village;
        locationAddress.city = data.address.city;
        locationAddress.country = data.address.country;
        locationAddress.countryCode = data.address.country_code;
        console.log(locationAddress);
        return locationAddress;
    }

    function fail() {
        return 'Fail...';
    }

    console.log(getLocationData())
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up returning a Promise with the coords instead of using localStorage and it worked :)

```
function geoFindMe() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      error('Geolocation is not supported by your browser');
    } else {
      elLocation.textContent = 'Locating…';
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, error);
    }
  });

  function error() {
    elLocation.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
    elNewsList.firstElementChild.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your country news';
  }
}

async function getLocationAddress() {
  const { latitude, longitude } = (await geoFindMe()).coords;
  let url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
}
```

Thanks for the help anyway!